# Deploying to Amazon Fire TV over USB

Tags: adb, kindle-fire

I've been working on an Amazon Fire TV app for about a month now.  The usual process of testing is to deploy over the network using Eclipse/adb.  However, as the size of my app has increased the deployment time has skyrocketed.  It has gotten to the point where it's painful to work on this platform and not worth the massive iteration time.  I'm about to cancel the whole project!

That being said, does anybody know how to deploy an app from my dev laptop to the Amazon Fire TV over USB?  I imagine that would be much faster.

Answer (score 1):

ADB over USB is not possible on the Fire TV, so you can't just connect it to a PC via USB. ADB over USB is possible on the Fire TV Stick however. ([source](http://www.aftvnews.com/fire-tv-stick-usb-port-not-for-power-only-adb-over-usb-confirmed/))

Your only option for the Fire TV is to [root it](http://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-root-the-amazon-fire-tv/). Rooting would allow you to connect an [external USB drive](http://www.aftvnews.com/how-to-move-and-run-amazon-fire-tv-apps-from-an-external-usb-storage-drive/) to the Fire TV using stickmount. You'd then need to use an app like a file explorer to install your APK off the USB drive.

Comment: Just wanted to update that it is now possible to upload over USB, so much faster (10x).